# em-dash or semicolon for this case?

Tags: punctuation, semicolons, em-dashes

I am trying to decide whether the semicolon or em-dash is the more appropriate punctuation mark in this case:

- It's not that I don't care -- it's just that I'm busy with other things.
- It's not that I don't care; it's just that I'm busy with other things.

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify which one is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the second clause is not breaking the flow of the enunciation, it seems to me that some other punctuation than the em-dash is better, comma or semicolon.